# Orthogonality in normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M$ and $N$ be nonzero closed vector subspaces of a normed vector space $E$. Prove that if $M \neq N$, then
$M^\perp \neq N^\perp$.

Comment: In general normed spaces, you don't have "orthogonality". You need the inner product structure.

Comment: Do you mean the annihilator $M^\perp = \{\lambda \in M' : (\forall x\in M)\lambda(x) = 0\}$?

Comment: @GhostAmarth yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniqueness of annihilator subspace in infinite dimensional normed space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491010/uniqueness-of-annihilator-subspace-in-infinite-dimensional-normed-space)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $M^\perp = N^\perp$, then by double annihilator theorem $\overline{M} = \overline{N}$. Since $M$ and $N$ are closed, it's a contradiction.

[If $X$ is a normed vector space and $U\subseteq X$, how do we show $(U^\perp)_\perp=\overline U$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009964/if-x-is-a-normed-vector-space-and-u-subseteq-x-how-do-we-show-u-perp-p#comment8277266_4009964)

Answer (score 1):

Although the question was answered in the post I linked, I thought I add some details.

Take w.l.o.g. $x\in M \setminus N$. Since $N$ is closed, $X/N$ is also a normed vector space and $q\colon X\to X/N, y \mapsto y+N$ is linear and continuous.

By Hahn-Banach, we can find a $\lambda \in (X/N)'$ such that $\lambda(x+N) = \|x+N\|_{X/N} \neq 0$, since $x\notin N$ (and therefore $x+N\neq N$).

Now $f=\lambda \circ q \in X'$ and $f|_N = 0$ but $f(x) \neq 0$, so $f\in N^\perp$ but $f\notin M^\perp$.